# context.RequestServices.GetService() resolving null

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am trying to get my user repository like this:

```
var userRepository = context.RequestServices.GetService<Repository<User>>();
```

But my problem is that it resolves null, I have it defined like so:

```
services.AddScoped(typeof(UserRepository), typeof(UserRepository));
```

And this is what the Repository class/interface look like:

```
public interface IRepository<T> where T : class, IAppEntity
{
    //Code
}

public abstract class Repository<T> : IRepository<T> where T : class, IAppEntity
{
    //Code
}
```

And this is the UserRepository:

```
public class UserRepository : Repository<User>
{
    public UserRepository(ApplicationDbContext context) : base(context)
    {
    }
}
```

And at last the User Model:

```
public class User : IdentityUser, IAppEntity
{
    //Code
}
```

Comment: First point: `services.AddScoped(typeof(UserRepository), typeof(UserRepository));` is wrong. You don't say that the implementation implements the implementation. That should be `services.AddScoped(typeof(IRepository<User>), typeof(UserRepository));`

Comment: Second point: `context.RequestServices.GetService<Repository<User>>();` not only that represents the service locator antipattern (so you shouldn't do that), but it's also wrong because the client **never** knows who is the implementer. That should be again `IRepository<User>`

Comment: Third point: you should read about Dependency Injection and SOLID in general. Also, what you are trying is mostly useless from the beginning. Don't wrap Entity Framework Core in a Repository

Comment: Shouldn't you do `services.AddScoped(Repository<User>, UserRepository);`

Comment: Well... Both solutions are working. So, thanks a lot! but you know what the funny thing is? The code is part mine and part from a fairly sized company I did an intership. They used this for like all there projects and I was thinking it was best practice all the time xD

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto is right.  In Entity Framework, DbContext is Unit of Work and DbSet<T> is Generic Repository.  When you wrap the abstraction behind your own abstraction you increase the complexity and you lose all the benefits that DbContext and DbSet<T> can bring to your application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are only registering the registration while you should register the interface with its implementation. For example:

```
services.AddScoped<IRepository<User>, UserRepository>();
```

After that, you can resolve the `IRepository<User>` service like this:

```
var userRepository = context.RequestServices.GetService<IRepository<User>>();
```

On a side note: resolving services like this is considered the [service locator anti-pattern](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2010/02/03/ServiceLocatorisanAnti-Pattern/). A better alternative is to inject the services into your constructor of the consuming services. For example:

```
public class MyService
{
    public MyService(IRepository<User> userRepository)
    {
        // Use userRepository...
    }
}
```